# Unnecessary rerenders with useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usecontext-wpozz)

```
function App() {
  const [value1, dispatch1] = useReducer(reducer, initialState1);
  const [value2, dispatch2] = useReducer(reducer, initialState2);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch1({ type: "setFirstName", firstName: "nick" });
        }}
      >
        change1
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch2({ type: "setFamilyName", familyName: "fname" });
        }}
      >
        change2
      </button>
      <JediContext1.Provider value={value1}>
        <Display1 />
      </JediContext1.Provider>
      <JediContext2.Provider value={value2}>
        <Display2 />
      </JediContext2.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I used two context per recommendation from [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693). But I might have misunderstood and maybe github issue is referring to another case? **Because it doesn't seem to solve my problem.**

The problem with above code is if I click `change1` button, which changes `value1`, component `Display2` **is also rerendered which doesn't even consume** `value1`.

Actually this makes sense to me because **I changed state in App, hence it would rerender all its children.** But then I don't understand the use of recommendation from the github link, because it didn't solve my problem here?

This maybe problematic performance wise if you have large app and root context provider say.

Comment: it's known thing but for unknown reason it has been discussed [just recently](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/f53ff7/that_react_component_right_under_your_context/). Is not related to hooks but only to how Context API works. Hope someone will compose fine answer with examples shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, not always, you want to memoize the `children` of your Providers to avoid that.
In this case, `Display1` and `Display2` could be PureComponent, or just

```
const Display1 = React.memo(() => <Whatever />)
```

The github issue that you linked refer to another issue: your provider's contains a lot of data, and you want to subscribe only to a slice of it. There may be cases where you update a value of the context, and it will re-render consumer that are not using that value. In that case, you may just want to split it in multiple context, as explained. But that's not your issue here.

Comment: 1)as soon as I update a Component which hosts the provider it causes all its children rerender anyway, so I can't see now example where the github recommendation fits, if you can elaborate on that too I am sure many people will find that useful. 
2) In my case, you said "usually not always"-are there alternatives you mean?

Comment: sorry, can you clarify what require more details/clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Try [memoizing both components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) so they only render when their local state changes:

```
const MemoDisplay = React.memo(Display1);
const MemoDisplay2 = React.memo(Display2);

function App() {
  ...
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      ...
      <JediContext1.Provider value={value1}>
        <MemoDisplay />
      </JediContext1.Provider>
      <JediContext2.Provider value={value2}>
        <MemoDisplay2 />
      </JediContext2.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hooks - useContext()]

Notice the logs, there is no unnecessary renders afterward.